# Why does the is keyword require a non-null expression?

Tags: c#, language-design, keyword

The MSDN documentation for the is keyword says:

```
expression is not null
```

Why? If *MethodThatReturnsNull() is type* were called shouldn't that return false since null certainly isn't that type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does return `false` if `expression` is `null`.  Perhaps you're misunderstanding the documentation?

Comment: Correct. MSDN states "An is expression evaluates to true if the provided expression is non-null, and the provided object can be cast to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown." So it is false if expression is null.

Comment: I've voted to close it since it's not really relevant anymore, considering my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can say for certain about null is that you don't know what it is.  Comparing something to null generally has a result of null ...

Q: Does 1 == "I don't know"?
A: "I dont know"

Check out [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/14/null-is-not-empty.aspx) by Eric Lippert.

Answer (score 0):

You can't statically resolve a null.

Answer (score 0):

This was a pretty popular answer I gave to a similar question.

[C# get type of null object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930147/c-get-type-of-null-object/930155#930155)

> That's like asking what kind of cake
>   would have been in an empty box with
>   no label.

Comment: According to the C# compiler and .NET framework, it's not a <i>type</i> cake. :)