# Nullable types in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

```
 protected static SqlParameter CreateParameter(string name, object value, bool skipEmpty, bool isOutput =false)
 {
    if (skipEmpty && value is string && string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))
        return null;
    //1
    if (skipEmpty && value is int? && value == null)
      return null;
    //2
    if (skipEmpty && value is Guid? && value == null)
      return null;
    //....................
}
```

The resharper says that 1 and 2 clauses are always false. But why?

Comment: @Jaimal Chohan, no, it is not a Resharper bug. It is a perfectly valid warning.

Comment: On the contrary @Jaimal... Resharper is right. Looks like you could do with a copy... it teaches you a lot.

Comment: Maybe use generics in your method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If value is null then it is impossible to infer a type more complex than `object` from it, therefore it can never be `int?` or `Guid?`

Answer (score 3):

if `value` is an `object`, and is null, what type was it? It doesn't have a type.

You've got a variable of type object, which doesn't contain anything. There's no way to know what someone else may have planned to place in that variable.

---

Or as the answer to [C# get type of null object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930147/c-get-type-of-null-object) put it:

> That's like asking what kind of cake would have been in an empty box with no label.

Answer (score 2):

An *is* expression evaluates to true if the provided expression is non-null. Therefore, the expression (value is int? && value == null) always equals false

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if (skipEmpty && ((value is string && string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value)) || value == null)) return null;
```

Comment: This should be a comment. It's not an answer.

Comment: Indeed, changed the answer and added a comment.

Comment: This should work more properly: if (value == null && skipEmpty)                 return null;

Comment: skipEmpty changes everything so you should evaluate it first.