# Getting type of not initialized variable

Tags: c#, reflection, initialization, gettype

There is main a variable which has uninitialized variables. I need to retrieve the Type of uninitialized varible type with reflection. Because I am generating the values dynamically but can't get the types of main variable's type of vars.

In the picture Quick Watch is showing the type name of `ameliyatGirisBilgileri` variable even it is not initialized.

[image: as shown in Type field of QuickWatch]

Comment: That picture is unreadable, and the description isn't terribly easy to understand either. Could you give a short but complete program which shows what you're trying to do?

Comment: while you're at it, perhaps rename `ameliyatGirisBilgileri' to something else as well

Comment: If it's a local variable then reflection will be useless, do you mean a class field or property?

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930147/c-sharp-get-type-of-null-object][1], check herzmeister's answer 3rd down.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930147/c-sharp-get-type-of-null-object

Comment: I'm gonna put better pictures. @vc74, yes I'm looking for type of property of `giris` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetField("ameliyatGirisBilgileri", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
Type fieldType = fieldInfo.FieldType;
```

Sorry but I'm too lazy to type the name of your class completely.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the `FieldInfo` for the variables within the type using the [`GetField(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1342sa7.aspx) or [`GetFields(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5z9w50.aspx) method on the main type. Below is a short program demonstrating how you might go about it:

```
class Program
{
    public string mStringType = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = new Program();

        try
        {
            var field = program.GetType().GetField("mStringType");

            Console.WriteLine("Field '{0}' is of type '{1}' and has value '{2}'.", field.Name, field.FieldType.FullName, field.GetValue(program));

            program.mStringType = "Some Value";

            Console.WriteLine("Field '{0}' is of type '{1}' and has value '{2}'.", field.Name, field.FieldType.FullName, field.GetValue(program));
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

This gives the following output on the Console window:

> Field 'mStringType' is of type 'System.String' and has value ''.
>
> Field 'mStringType' is of type 'System.String' and has value 'Some Value'.

Note: If the fields are not `public`, you will have to pass some `BindingFlags` into the `GetField(...)` or `GetFields(...)` methods.