# How to get the Model type in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I find out the type of a View's Model within the View itself?

I tried doing calling `GetType`:

```
@model MyModel

<div>@Model.GetType()</div>
```

which works unless the `Model` is null, in which case I get a `NullReferenceException`.

Unfortunately it's also not possible to do

```
@model MyModel

<div>@typeof(TModel)</div>
```

as `TModel` is not available in the context of the Razor view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
@ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType
```

Works whether the model's value is null or not and it's built right in. No need for creating a helper.

Comment: Amazing. This is much more elegant than my solution.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is by creating a helper extension on `HtmlHelper<TModel>`

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static Type GetModelType<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper)
    {
        return typeof(TModel);
    }
}
```

Which you can then use like so

```
@using HtmlHelperExtensions
@model MyModel

<div>@Html.GetModelType()</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if it's null first, then get the type, ie:

```
@if(Model != null) {
<div>@Model.GetType()</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although this would solve the exception, it means that the type wouldn't be displayed if it is `null`.

Comment: So you want the type, whether it is null or not? If that is the case, I believe you can not get the type of a null object. - You can see here for more information - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930147/c-sharp-get-type-of-null-object. I think my solution is as close as you can get, if you add an "else" with "unknown type".